# Computing the volume of a region bounded by polynomial inequalities

Tags: polynomials, volume

I am interested in computing the volume of the following region, as a function of $X$:

$$\displaystyle \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : |x|, |y|, |z^2 - 4xy| \geq 1, |xy(z^2 - 4xy)^2| \leq X\}.$$

This region is bounded and closed, hence compact, so it must have finite volume. Does anyone know how to do the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

The region is symmetric with respect to the joint symmetry operation $x \to -x$ and $y \to -y$, and $z$ appears only as a square, so there are only two octants you need integrate, e.g., $x>0, y>0, z>0$ and $x>0, y<0, z<0$.

Incidentally, here is the region for $X = 4000$:

[image]

It is an ugly integral, but simple to perform numerically for fixed $X$ (and which gives for $X = 4000$ the value $2813$).

---

I'd be interested in how this problem arose.

Comment: The function $f(A,B,C) = 16AC(B^2 - 4AC)^2$ is the discriminant of the quartic polynomial $Ax^4 + Bx^2 + C$, and I am trying to count these things ordered by (absolute) discriminant. The other conditions are to ensure that the discriminant is non-zero, and that the constant term and the leading coefficient are non-zero (since they are non-zero and integer, it must be at least one in absolute value)